# Get last added values in data key as an array of a following json format

Tags: angularjs

I have the following json data in my api

```html
[
       {
"_id": "586a487faacfbfcc3d3073b2",
"data": {
"temp": 420,
"humidity": 200
},
"timestamp": "2017-01-02T12:33:03.572Z"
},
{
"_id": "586cdbc1bfdfee651e8b6490",
"data": {
"humidity": 250
},
"timestamp": "2017-01-04T11:25:53.748Z"
},
{
"_id": "586ce6fbdb6b3d2025b526ba",
"data": {
"temp": 95,
"humidity": 250
},
"timestamp": "2017-01-04T12:13:47.102Z"
},
{
"_id": "586d19c8db6b3d2025b526bb",
"data": {
"humidity": 350
},
"timestamp": "2017-01-04T15:50:32.259Z"
},
{
"_id": "586d1a77db6b3d2025b526bc",
"data": {
"humidity": 250
},
"timestamp": "2017-01-04T15:53:27.146Z"
}
]
```

-So now i need "last" added values of temp,humidity or any other dynamically added propeties' values in an array.
-Next suppose i need last added value of any property say only humidity it should be put into an array.Here comparison of keys should be done and matched keys value should be retrieved (last added value).
so if user enters "temp": he should get [95], if he enters "temp","humidity": he should get [95,250]
-I need to pass this array to gauge charts(currently using zingcharts-angularjs).

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: I get the last record where humidity:250 but temp:undefined...so i need last added temp value i.e 95

Comment: this is real time data ,so as soon as data is added the value of array should be updated

Comment: it needs lot of code, may be can help with the logic

Comment: just add a $scop.watch for your variable, whenever its getting updated do a angular.forEach for the array data and get the last element and update the value of temp to it